# Problem upgrading Mac Pro to macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mojave, upgrade, raid

I have macOS El Capitan on my Mac Pro and I am trying to update my Mac Pro to macOS High Sierra so I can update it to Mojave since Mojave requires to have at least macOS High Sierra. But when I run the installer I get the below error. Any advice on the steps needed to overcome this issue?

[image]

This is my Mac Pro specs:

[image]

This is my disks in Disk utility:

[image]

Comment: idk how to fix your RAID issue, but you won't be able to upgrade to Mojave with that GPU. You'll need a Metal2-capable card. I put a Mac-flashed AMD HD 7950 in mine.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, I bought a Sapphire Pulse Radeon RX 580  but I am not sure if I should install it now or wait until I upgrade to macOS High Sierra first?
I don't care about the data now on the RAID setup, as I bought a Samsung 970 EVO Plus to place it in the PCIe and will use it as the OS drive and the 2x2TB will be just to store data so I need to have the current 2TB hard drives have Mojave so that when the SSD arrive I can do a clone of the OS to it and then wipe the 2TB harddrives to use for data. I hope I explained it well?

Comment: I presume you have your data all nicely backed up & ready to migrate in afterwards? If your Sapphire is Mac-flashed you could put it in any time. If it isn't, then right before the actual Mojave upgrade, otherwise you'll struggle pre-login. If this RAID is truly unimportant, then you could sacrifice one temporarily to become an installer - you can run the 'create installer' straight to an HD, it doesn't have to be a USB stick [faster too]. Wait for the SSD to go in [reset SMC, v important for PCI-mounted drives] & clean install to that, then upgrade to Mojave. Make sense?

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for your help. I don't have data on the RAID except the macOS. How to know if my Sapphire is Mac-flashed? And how I can set one of the drives as a temporary installer? I mean could you advise me with the steps or send me a link showing how?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/HT201372 to create the installer; you can do that to *any* HFS volume [most people don't have the ability to put half a dozen drives in their laptops, so we get more room to play with on a Mac Pro ;) idk any definitive way to test for Mac-flashed other than see if you get a picture before the login screen [that's the definitive test, no Mac flash, no image until login [which means you cannot use FileVault, btw]. Don't forget to reset SMC after *any* hardware change; odd things can happen if you don't.

Comment: SMC - shut down, pull mains out, count 15s, then hold power button for 15s [then let go], re-plug mains, count 5. Boot. [Last time I did it I forgot the 15s hold & stuff went weird]

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you, will try that out. So is it good that I will use a NVMEI ssd as my OS drive? I thought it would be faster than a normal 2.5” ssd. Also will my wifi and bluetooth work after upgrading to Mojave?

Comment: I have a regular SATA III SSD on a PCIe card, never tried NVME, probably faster still. Wifi will be fine, BT may depend on which card. Handoff requires a modern BT4/BTLE card [$175… ouch!], but 'regular' stuff should still be as before.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am glad to hear that :) and will Airdrop work?

Comment: That's probably dependant on the above BTLE card too.

Comment: @Tetsujin  Kindly find the bluetooth details here https://www.dropbox.com/s/5pxbybciudixhvh/Photo%2019-6-20%2C%2012%2005%2017%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: We're getting far beyond your initial question, but no, that quite clearly says not supported.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for your help and apologies for the other questions.

Comment: @Tetsujin Just to confirm, so if I upgrade to Mojave then my wireless bluetooth magic mouse and keyboard won’t work as well?